# DataSource Must not be null Spring boot 2.5.7 Upgrade- JUnit testcase fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[This is my data source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKY1f.png)

Here is some description.
java. lang. IllegalArgumentException: DataSource must not be null

```
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.SingleDataSourceLookup.<init>(SingleDataSourceLookup.java:40)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:257)
at org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder$Builder.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder.java:234)
at com.cardinalhealth.nphsden.framework.utils.DbUtils.getEntityManagerFactory(DbUtils.java:38)
at com.cardinalhealth.nphsden.framework.utils.DbUtilsTest.testGetEntityManagerFactory(DbUtilsTest.java:53)
```

Comment: Please prefer copy/paste your code than show it as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**use this - >**
pgDataSource = dataSourceBuilder.create().build();

**instead of - >**
pgDataSource = dataSourceBuilder.build();